# How to make in CCK a field like a grid

Tags: entities

In my site I want user to add a new album of images 
he have to add 
 1. title
 2. description
 3. sub form that contain Image and title and set to default (radio button) and he can add   more than one sub form

and only one image will be the default site that will appear in home page (Selected from radio button)

How can I make things like that

Comment: Could you rephrase the question slightly?  The first part is relatively easy to understand but you start to lose me at #3

Comment: #3 user can add more than one Image and set one of them as a default image using radio button

Answer (score 1):

Presuming CCK=>Drupal 6, and without writing a custom module or custom compound CCK type, you could do something like this:

1. Create a cck content type, let's call it album_image, and in it have the following fields:

   a.  Image field
   b.  text field for title
   c.  text area for description
2. Allow your users to create/edit these content types and fields via permissions
3. Create a view that returns all album_images created by the logged in user
4. Add a node reference field to the user's profile (The Content Profile module is an easy way to do this) and restrict it to one result, and call it for discussion here default_image.
5. Within CCK screens for the field above, use the view you created above to populate the "returned values" for the node reference instead of just selecting a content type.
6. Now, when your user edits his or her profile, they can select one album_image as the one they want displayed.

Now within your user profiles you have a field called field_default_image that contains the nid of the album_image your user wants to have displayed on his or her profile, so you can then load that up to get the image and use that wherever you need, eg, within whatever preprocess functions you use within your theme to paint the profile.

Comment: it is Drupal 7and I want to make this as a field to add more Image can I make it with Drupal or custom field.Thanks

Comment: the above should work for d7, too.